# innerHTML changing href with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, innerhtml

We had below HTML code - a button with image.

```
<button id="BT_ADD_ROW_P_1" class="icon-btn-enabled" onclick="addRow_P_1();" title="Add Row" type="button" style="display: block;">
<img class="icon-image-2-enabled" alt="Add Row" src="/itg/images/pm/insertRowTransparent.gif"></img></button>
```

clicking the above button would call **`addRow_P_1()`** function.
Now I have another function to change its event

```
document.getElementById('BT_ADD_ROW_'+tableObject.id).onclick=function(){TBC_AddRow(tableObject);};
```

Using above code, when the button is clicked instead of calling **`addRow_P_1`** function the TBC_AddRow was called. This is the existing functionality which ws working good till now.

After upgrade the basic HTML code was changed. The button was replaced and the below code is used.

```
<a id="BT_ADD_ROW_P_1" class="tc-btn-enabled" href="javascript:addRow_P_1('BT_ADD_ROW_P_1');" hidefocus="true"><span><img alt="Add Row" src="/itg/images/table/add.png"></img>Add Row </span></a>
```

I had modified the JS function to below but it's not working...

```
document.getElementById('BT_ADD_ROW_'+tableObject.id).innerHTML='<a class="tc-btn-enabled" href="javascript:TBC_AddRow('+tableObject+');"><span><img alt="Add Row" src="/itg/images/table/add.png"></img>Add Row</span></a>';
```

Could someone please me fix this? I'm new and don't much about how the innerHTML works.. Thanks.

Comment: When you were typing your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area. Worth a read. There was also a full toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button providing all sorts of useful information. And a preview area underneath the text area where you could check the result. Please use them.

Comment: which browser/s are you using?

Comment: @Arun - You need to tell your employer that they are designing for obsolescence. IE8 support will be [dropped completed in almost exactly 10 months](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=PN&alpha=internet+explorer).

Comment: Yes I agree, in couple of months, we would be going to IE10/11..
but currently I need to make this code work...